# TextToColumns Run-time error '424' Object required

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a TextToColumns macro on all open workbooks.  This Macro works on 1 book. i.e. I open 1 book and I run the macro.  But when I try to run it on all open workbooks via another VBA macro i get the Run-time error '424' Object required.

I have tried multiple things to fix this.  Also if I just step through the macro (Hold F8) the macro runs fine.

Here is what is in Column A:

6/10/2014 0:02

its copied all the way down to the bottom.

```
Sub S()
Dim wbkx As Workbook
    For Each wbkx In Application.Workbooks
        wbkx.Activate
        Worksheets(1).Select
        Columns("A:A").Select
        If Selection.Column <> "" Then
            Call WTF
        Else
            MsgBox ("Fail!")
        End If
    Next wbkx
End Sub

Sub WTF()
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("I1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(18, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
        True
        Columns("I:I").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Columns("A:A").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("J:K").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted?

Comment: Selection.TextToColumns....

Comment: What is the purpose of `If Selection.Column <> ""`?  That returns a number in Long format of the column index so it will ALWAYS be non-blank.

Comment: I put that in there because I was getting an error of Run-time error '1004' No data was selected to parse

Answer (score 0):

It is considered bad practice to use selections.  Also I don't think you need two subs:

```
Sub S()
Dim wbkx As Workbook, SelSht As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, CurRow As Long, _
    DateA As String, YearA As String, MonthA As String, DayA As String
    For Each wbkx In Application.Workbooks
        wbkx.Activate
        Set SelSht = wbkx.Worksheets(1)
        LastRow = SelSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For CurRow = 1 To LastRow
            DateA = SelSht.Range("A" & CurRow).Value
            MonthA = Mid(DateA, 1, InStr(1, DateA, "/") - 1)
            DayA = Mid(DateA, InStr(1, DateA, "/") + 1, (InStr(InStr(1, DateA, "/") + 1, DateA, "/") - InStr(1, DateA, "/") - 1))
            YearA = Mid(DateA, InStr(InStr(1, DateA, "/") + 1, DateA, "/") + 1, (InStr(1, DateA, " ") - InStr(InStr(1, DateA, "/") + 1, DateA, "/") - 1))
            SelSht.Range("A" & CurRow).Value = DateSerial(CInt(YearA), CInt(MonthA), CInt(DayA))
        Next CurRow
    Next wbkx
End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried this got a Run-time error '1004': No data was selected to parse.  The entire SelSht.columns("A:A").TextToColumns.... was selected the arrow pointed at the line w/ True

Comment: I put what the data in column A is in my answer "11/20/2014"

Comment: Is that a date stored as date?  You just need the month?

Comment: sorry the data is "6/10/2014 0:02" I need to remove the time at the end and keep the date

Comment: Try my new updated code.  Just changes it to a date only using `DateSerial`

Comment: Are you sure the Value is stored as a Date?  Or is it stored as a string?

Comment: If it is a string, I updated my code above to handle the string conversion to date with `CDate()`

Comment: Still an error its Run-time error '13' Type mismatch...DateA = CDate(Selsht.Range("A" & CurRow).Value) is highlighted.

Comment: Looks like your string is not being recognized as a date.  Let me make some changes and I will post on here when it is edited.

Comment: Updated to handle string

Comment: no I couldn't get anything to work for this i just ended up F8'ing through it on all the different workbooks